# Regex replace consecutive non-alpha chars with single char

Tags: .net, regex

I want to replace all non-alpha characters in a string with a plus '+' sign, but making sure that a group of more than one non-alpha chars is only replaced by one plus sign.

I had thought the following might work but apparently not:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(name, @"[^\w]*?", "+")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(name, @"\W+", "+")

For this: "sasa-==[]*&^asdsa2435" matches -==[]*&^

Comment: One small caveat: using \W will exclude letters, numbers *and* underscores from the match. Use [^A-Za-z] instead if you only want to exclude letters, or [^0-9A-Za-z] to exclude alphanumerics (but include underscores).

Answer (score 0):

You should not disable greediness, and you want 1 or more, not 0 or more.  Replace "*?" with "+".